# Regular expression ignores text "(10)"

Tags: c#, regex

I am using this regular expression to find exact strings but it tends to ignore following strings,

This works,

```
var textFragmentAbsorber = new TextFragmentAbsorber(@"internal(?=\s|$)");
```

This doesn't,

```
var textFragmentAbsorber = new TextFragmentAbsorber(@"internal (10) Ab(?=\s|$)");
```

By doesn't work I mean it doesn't finds the text   "internal (10) Ab"

[Full code reference](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/606647.aspx)

Text I am getting is from web services, so all I can do is add regex at end... it can be (10) or ((((( 1000 , i can't imagine

Comment: Try using [txt2re](http://txt2re.com/) in the future, it'll prevent those errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
internal \(10\) Ab(?=\s|$)
```

You need to escape `()`.`()` has special meaning and it is used for grouping.If you want literal `()` you have to escape it.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/8

If it can be `(10)` or `((((10000))))`

Then try `internal \(*\d+\)* Ab(?=\s|$)`

Comment: We will have some Chai or even stronger drinks at your big party then maybe let's see... :)

Answer (score 4):

In regex `()` are special meta characters which represents the start and end of a capturing group. You need to escape the brackets in-order to match a literal `(`, `)` symbols.

```
var textFragmentAbsorber = new TextFragmentAbsorber(@"internal \(10\) Ab(?=\s|$)");
```